# ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: сокет, websocket, ssl, port

Попытка присоединить сокет к порту через безопасный сертификат `var socket = new WebSocket("wss://46.229.214.83:8030");` вызывает ошибку

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://46.229.214.83:8030/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

К сайту подлючен сертификат Let's encrypt SSL, не лично мной подписанный. При смене `wss` на `ws` антивирус блокирует выполнение скрипта. Как исправить эту ошибку, при этом подключаясь по `wss`?

Comment: А может антивирус и сертификат переопределяет?

Comment: @Zergatul антивирус блокирует скрипт, который соединяется с ws, а присоединение с wss нормально пропускает, а сам скрипт даёт ошибку, в т.ч. на тех устройствах, где антивирус не установлен